# Xmodmap remapping Caps, but still triggering Caps Lock

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

Im using CentOS 6.5 workstation, pretty standard config, with normal dell keyboard, EN/US lang and keyboard layout. I have the following in the .Xmodmap

```
keycode 66 = Control_L
clear Lock
add Control = Control_L
keycode 117 = Caps_Lock
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

Which maps Caps to Ctrl as I desire. A few times a day I somehow trigger caps lock, sometimes in the browser, sometimes from the shell, there seems no pattern to it yet there must be. I can't figure out what Im actually pressing after the event, but more to question, what combination would enable one to toggle caps lock when the above config is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear lock
clear control
add control = Caps_Lock Control_L Control_R
keycode 66 = Control_L Caps_Lock NoSymbol NoSymbol
```

This will remap Caps_Lock to control and allow you to use Shift+Caps_Lock to trigger the normal behaviour of Caps_Lock

Comment: This is a much better config. Thanks. However I still wonder what the hell I was pressing to trigger caps with the original config as it seems pretty much bullet proof and I cant brute force an answer with trying.

Comment: `keycode 177` seems to be `Page Down`, that would be triggering caps lock since you're mapping it to it.